# How to change the background color on AS400 / IBM in Windows 10?

Tags: ibm-midrange

When, I was using Windows 7, the procedure was simple to change the background color.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS9FA_14.0.0/com.ibm.hod.doc/help/mapdefault.html

Today, I installed Windows 10 and when I modifie the background color. After each time of booting the machine the background color stays white. (by default)

I always must (every day) to change the settings to set my colors.

Comment: In order to help you, we need to know which client you are using to connect to the IBMi. Are you using Access Client Solutions (ACS), Client Access Solutions (older version of the previous tool), or some other client?

Comment: @Player1st: Thank you for your help, in Protocol,  I read `Use IBM i Access Client Solutions Setting`